502 error occurs in one of my templates when I run flask
Everytime I run flask and I input my data, I get a 502 error message regarding this process.
It is linked to the following code:
If request.method == "POST": a = request.form.get("a") db.execute("INSERT INTO b (c) VALUES "a"") Everything before works perfect.  
I want to correct the error.
I restarted my lapop, removed the db and passed in anoher one.
I thought it is may liked to the database. Outside of the code I am able to insert data to the db. The db includes trigger to insert new data.
